# Interpreting LED output distribution specification

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes, luminosity

I have specifications for an LED which gives the following graph of spacial output distribution.

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret this. As I see it, it could be one of two ways.

To make explanations easier, assume there is a spherical dome placed around the LED such that any point on the dome is the same distance from the LED.

**Idea 1:**

The brightness on the point of the dome directly above the LED is twice that of roughly 64 degrees of centre. (Reading directly from the graph).

Conceptually, this means the graph is like a cross section (symmetrical around the LED)?

**Idea 2:**

The graph represents the total power output, rather than a cross section. So, to get the relative brightness at a point on the dome, I need to use the inverse square law or similar, since for any angle on the graph, the power emitted by the LED at that angle has to be spread over a greater circumference on the dome for larger angles on the graph.

**My question:** Is my first, or second idea the correct interpretation? (And if it's the second idea, at what angle would the brightness on the dome be half that (power per unit area) of the point on the dome directly above the LED?)

I hope my question makes sense, and is on topic. I'm hoping that for worst case scenario (e.g. not enough data on the LED), this LED's distribution is a common/recognisable phenomena.

Thanks

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a cross-section, and your first idea is the correct one. This is similar to antenna radiation plots, and other angular distribution plots.

Comment: @JonCuster is correct.  Note that in your Idea 2, the points on your sphere are all the same distance from the source, so there's no inverse square law involved.   Also, the power emitted at larger angles is *not* spread out over greater circumference on the dome.  With those two points in mind, Idea 2 is the same as Idea 1.

Comment: @Garyp unless I misunderstand you, I disagree, because the light landing on the dome directly above the LED (zero degrees on the graph) is landing on a single point, whereas, at 90 degrees, that light would be falling across the full circumference of the dome? In a sense, an infinitely larger "area" (distance = area in this case, my calculus isn't good enough to explain, I hope it makes sense)

Comment: No, I misunderstood you.   Idea 1 is the correct interpretation.